# Access shared preference value in data module in clean architecture Android

Tags: android, kotlin, clean-architecture

I want to read shared preference value from presentation module into data module, as my presentation module is dependent on "data" and "domain" module.

it became a circular dependency to access shared preference in data module.

Please guide me, as I am following clean architecture.

Comment: what your expecting output??

Comment: Need to access token captured through SSO and saved in shared preference.

Comment: Found way to expose it in data layer.